# Problem with WordPress custom user role - do not have permission

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I try to add a new role for SEO specialist. This is my array in functions.php:

```
add_role('seosem', __(
   'seosem'),
   array(
       'read'                    => true,
       'create_posts'            => true,
       'edit_posts'              => true,
       'edit_others_posts'       => true,
       'publish_posts'           => true,
       'edit_others_pages'       => true,
       'edit_published_pages'    => true,
       'edit_published_posts'    => true,
       'publish_pages'           =>true,
       'delete_pages'            =>true,
       'delete_others_pages'     =>true,
       'delete_published_pages'  =>true,
       )
);
```

But when I try to login on this account. I can't edit posts & pages created by admin, and create a new pages. This user has no permission. How to fix it? As you can see everything in set on TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I think the role has already been created. Please delete it and recreate it.
Type this code before **add_role** function:

```
if ( get_role( 'seosem' ) ) {
     remove_role( 'seosem' );
}
```